# USB stick (HP V210W 16GB) mounts on MBP 13" running OS X 10.5.8, but not on MBP 13" running 10.6.8

Tags: usb, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

My brother bought a HP V210W 16GB usb stick. It wasn't recognized by his MBP 13" (2011, 2.7GHz i7, 4GB 1333MHz DDR3) running OS X 10.6.8. He then tried the stick on his Win7 PC which recognized it just fine, and formatted the stick as FAT32. It still didn't work on his MBP: didn't mount, wasn't recognized in Finder, didn't show up in Disk Utility or System Profiler.

On my MBP 13" (2009, 2.53GHz Core2Duo, 4GB 1067MHz DDR3) running OS X 10.5.8 it works fine: it gets recognized and I can access the files on it. Erased everything using Disk Utility, re-formatted as FAT32. Still doesn't work on his MBP.

Is this an issue caused by hardware (either Mac or USB stick), formatting/partitioning (FAT32), operating system (Snow Leopard vs Leopard) or something entirely different?

Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB stick in his MBP? A printer? Some other USB device?

Answer (score 0):

My HPv210w USB stick worked fine on my MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion for a while until recently it wouldn't show up in Finder. Strangely I was able to move files to it.

I tried shutting down then **logging on as 'Guest User'.**

Hey presto! there was the HP stick with all its files accessible.

Next stage was to back up the stick to my external hard drive.
Then it was just a case of opening Disc Utilities, repairing and reformatting the stick and shutting down.

When I restarted in normal passworded mode the stick was showing again in Finder.